# Best way to create an enum model class for google app engine in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design

I would like to create a base enum class which itself inherits from db.Model.  The idea would be to create several helper functions that would be available for any descendent of the enum class.  The properties might very to some extend, but there would be several common properties that I could declare in the base enum class ('Name', for example).  Is there a standard way of dealing with enumeration models in App Engine?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but ProtoRPC Message properties for NDB include EnumProperty: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#msgprop

Comment: I did see that while searching for a solution; unfortunately, it's not quite what I need.  I need a full enum class for which I can write specialized methods.

Comment: You are likely covering new ground; enums aren't that popular.  Might be worth solving it yourself and posting back here with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you will have to write your own property type class (you can probably extend db.IntegerProperty). [Nick Johnson's ChoiceModel class is an example](https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon/blob/master/__init__.py#L496) of how to do that:

```
  This works by mapping each choice to an integer.  The choices must be hashable
  (so that they can be efficiently mapped back to their corresponding index).

  Example usage:

  >>> class ChoiceModel(db.Model):
  ...   a_choice = ChoiceProperty(enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue']))
  ...   b_choice = ChoiceProperty([(0,None), (1,'alpha'), (4,'beta')])

  You interact with choice properties using the choice values:

  >>> model = ChoiceModel(a_choice='green')
  >>> model.a_choice
  'green'
  >>> model.b_choice == None
  True
  >>> model.b_choice = 'beta'
  >>> model.b_choice
  'beta'
```

(The linked code and quoted comments is released under the Apache license; copyright 2011 Nick Johnson.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please expand the relevant parts of the link in your answer. If the link breaks, so does this answer, which means it won't help anyone in the future. Otherwise, your answer may be removed.